# How to Invite someone to Chat that's not already in a chat room?

Tags: support, chat

The FAQ says to use the Edit Room menu, but I didn't see any such menu.

In other chat systems, INVITE USER was a big, obvious, and frequently-used button.

Am I blind?

EDIT: new feature requested [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/can-we-get-a-simple-way-to-initiate-a-chat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the FAQ is lying. I don't know how that sentence slipped in there, but that's not true nor ever was. I'll update it.

You have two ways to invite a user. Either through the little user popup in the life chat:

[image: inviting through the user popup]

or on the user's profile page:

[image: inviting through the profile page]

Both lists will show you all rooms you can invite the user to, which are rooms that satisfy the following conditions:

- You are already in it.
- The invitee isn't in there yet (and hasn't been invited there either).
- The invitee has the right to talk in the room.

Comment: And there's no way to invite someone who hasn't been to chat short of posting a comment, right?

Comment: @AnnaLear: Yep, that's correct (except for moderators).

Comment: @balpha: the inability to invite someone to chat severely limits its usefulness. Anna, for example, is _notorious_ for telling people to stop discussing things in comments and take it to chat, yet there is no simple way to actually do so. Will add this as a feature request.

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe: *stop discussing things in comments and take it to chat, yet there is no simple way to actually do so* -- As you should have noticed at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/85377/acceptance-tests-done-first-how-can-this-be-accomplished/85379#85379, this is no longer true as of today

Comment: @balpha: what is no longer true, that there is now a simple way to 'take it to chat' or that discussions in comments are no longer taboo? I understand the desire to limit chit-chat in the comments ("too localized"), just couldn't figure out how to get a chat session going...

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe: Do you not see the "automatically move to chat" link when you click "add / show more comments" on that post?

Comment: @balpha: nope, don't see it

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe: Well, now you don't anymore, beause Anna broke it :) If you post another comment *right here*, you should see it as well.

Comment: @balpha: ok i'm posting another comment _right here_. Here it goes!

Comment: @balpha: ooh shiny!

Comment: @balpha: want to update this question with the new feature? http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/can-we-get-a-simple-way-to-initiate-a-chat

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe: Already typing :)