# Can we get a simple way to initiate a chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, stackexchange

The answer to [this chat-related question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1761/how-to-invite-someone-to-chat-thats-not-already-in-a-chat-room) leads to a feature request:

A simple way to notify and invite someone to chat regardless of whether they've ever chatted before or not.

Story:

```
As a [stackexchange user] 
I want to [invite another user to chat] 
So that [we can continue our discussion easily]
```

ADENDUM: for archival purposes it might make sense to auto-create a room for discussions started in the comments of a particular question/answer. Yes, this effectively turns SO into a forum - but it keeps the discussiony stuff out of the main Q&A stuff, which I think was the point of having a separate chat system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feature actually already exists. We're still experimenting with it, but it has been activated this morning on all sites except for Stack Overflow:

[image]

(note the "automatically move this discussion to chat" link). This link is visible to you and me, because we're having a back-and-forth discussion in the comments. At the moment this is still voluntary; at some point, we may start blocking further comments, thus *forcing* (not just *suggesting*) to take it to chat.

Clicking the link will create a new room in chat, copy our comment discussion into that room, and leave an automatic "let's take this to chat" comment on behalf of the user who clicked.

Comment: awesome! will use this in future

Comment: Oh my, this is awesome.

Comment: Great!  Is there a way to trigger this without a long discussion, or to force it as a mod?

Answer (score 4):

I think it'd be nice to have an "invite to chat" link in a user profile similar to the ones already in the chat profiles.

That said, this has been brought up on [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70385/add-invite-user-to-chat-function-on-main-site) before and while it wasn't outright [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), it received a lukewarm response at best.

Comment: I was originally against the chat system (SO is not a social-media forum) but now that we have it, it should be easily usable for its intended purposes. Especially since a _certain someone_ is fond of telling people to go there ;-)

Comment: @Steven I'd really appreciate it if you'd stop doing that. I simply respond to long comment threads that we are alerted about and other moderators haven't yet handled. As I said [elsewhere](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/85377/acceptance-tests-done-first-how-can-this-be-accomplished/85379#85379), it's a [general policy](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/how-do-our-moderators-and-community-members-feel-about-cleaning-up-comment-nois/1508#1508) not my personal whim.

Comment: OK sorry, I'll stop teasing you. For now ;-)